# NodeJs CI/CD on shared hosting cpanel

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, cpanel, continuous-deployment, shared-hosting

I want to know how to implemented CI/CD pipeline for nodeJs with shared hosting cpanel. I tried with SSH keys but I'm stuck when running `sudo` command because my account is shared hosting and don't have root access to run `sudo` command.

Please let me know if anyone knows how to do that. I searched many times on google but I found nothing for shared hosting CI/CD for nodeJs.

Comment: Can you give more details? CI/CD with cpanel does not make sense in my head, so I must be missing something. Usually, one would run CI/CD where the source code is stored, e.g. GitHub. I've also never seen a cpanel host that supports Nodejs. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your question has alot of bugs(not making any sense)

Answer (score 0):

Access rights might depend on the kind how node.js is installed.
CPanel provides an own documentation how to install node.js and
[how to create an SSL include file for an addon domain if required](https://docs.cpanel.net/knowledge-base/web-services/how-to-install-a-node.js-application/).

Note that as this question is not code related Stack Overflow might not the best place to ask this question. I'd advisee to search also on other [stackexchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) like [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/), [superuser](https://superuser.com/) or some different sites there.